# Updating github.io domain AND redirecting from old github.io domain (neatest method)

Tags: url, github, rename, github-pages

I recently created a GitHub account and website for a group project with the following format:

```
https://abc123.github.io/
```

Due to changes outside my control, the name of the website should now be of the following format:

```
https://abc124.github.io/
```

Since we have already used our old website name (https://abc123.github.io/) publicly, we want to not entirely destroy that link, but simply have it redirect to the new website (https://abc124.github.io/).

My plan is to 1) clone the abc123 repository, 2) open a new GitHub account abc124, 3) push the old clone to the new GitHub account abc124, change the old repository to have a message asking users to click on a link connecting them to https://abc124.github.io/. The downside of this is that I now unnecessarily have TWO GitHub accounts and users are bothered to have to click on a link.

I would like to ask if anyone has ideas on a better method. What is the neatest and easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: In case it is of interest, I ended up using advice here: https://gist.github.com/domenic/1f286d415559b56d725bee51a62c24a7.